# How to share location in a group with glympse rest api

Tags: glympse

I am trying to share my location to a card with following steps:

1. create a ticket with API `/users/self/create_ticket`
2. set the card_id of the ticket with API `/tickets/:id/append_data`
3. share ticket to a card with API `/cards/:id/ticket`, invite_code: random string like pUsl_79rB
4. append location into the ticket whit API `/tickets/:id/append_location`

Then I retrieve card members with API `/cards/:id?members=true,` I can see the ticket just created and shared to the card.

But the problem is that the invite_code is always "00" like following:
"ticket": {**"invite_code": "00"**, "ticket_id": "160064993", "created_time": 1506573004818}

With invite_code "00", no one can get the location I shared.

Please help.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create invite code for the ticket created in step 1). So your step 1.1) would involve calling `POST tickets/:id/create_invite?type=link'. This will provide you with the code that goes to the card in step 3).